# Monomorphism between finite Boolean algebras

Tags: boolean-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite Boolean algebra. If I define a monomorphism (i.e. an injective homomorphism) from $A$ to another finite Boolean algebra $B$ of the same similarity type. Is this monomorphism an isomorphism?

I am tempted to think that yes, for two Boolean algebras which have the same number of elements are isomorphic. But I would like a second opinion to be sure...

Comment: What do you mean by "similarity type"?

Comment: @EricWofsey. I mean same signature.

Comment: What is the "signature" of a Boolean algebra?

Comment: @EricWofsey. Boolean algebras can have many different signatures (a term rather found in logic) or similarity types (rather found in universal algebra). For instance, a Boolean algebra can be defined in terms of join and complement. Or, join, meet, and complement, etc... Typically, a Boolean algebra would be written $(A,\vee,\wedge,-)$ for instance. $(\vee,\wedge,-)$ is the type or signature of $A$.

Answer (score 4):

No, this isn't true, because the homomorphism need not be surjective.  For instance, $f:X\to Y$ is any surjective map of finite sets, then the inverse image map $f^{-1}:P(Y)\to P(X)$ is an injective homomorphism of finite Boolean algebras.  But $P(Y)$ and $P(X)$ have different cardinalities if $X$ and $Y$ have different cardinalities, in which case $f^{-1}$ is not an isomorphism.

Comment: +1. A simpler counterexample: there's a monomorphism from the 2-element Boolean algebra to any Boolean algebra (send top to top and bottom to bottom).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: To any Boolean algebra except the Boolean algebra with one element!

Comment: Aaargh . . . :P Quite right, quite right (and here I am with a universal algebra textbook even! no excuse. sigh).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, for instance, if both Boolean algebras have the same cardinality (or same number of elements), is any monomorphism from $A$ to $B$ an isomorphism?

Comment: @student: Yes, because any injection between two finite sets of the same cardinality is a bijection.

Comment: @EricWofsey. Thanks!

Comment: @student Note that this crucially assumes that the Boolean algebras in question are *finite* - that said, it also holds for all types of structures, not just Boolean algebras, as long as they are finite.